# DIY pedal board without a hinged lid

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I'm looking to make a DIY pedal board.  I have all the necessary wood and tools, and I want to be able to have it closed with a cover, for protection while going to gigs.  The trick is, I can't have a swinging (hinged) lid, because often we play on small stages, and the open lid would take up extra space while the board is open.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Pictures and/or links would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hinges that are 'open'. They act like hinges until at 90 degrees, then split. Or - use a small version of the hasp and staple used on gates. They are available for small cupboards, and once open, the lid can slide sideways and come off the pins.Rather like 'rising butt' hinges found on some doors.

A really cheap and cheerful solution is to use a briefcase (£1 or £2 from a car boot sale) and put foam in it. The top will stay up while in use.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this is without hinges anyway. Build it using the catches you usually see on flight cases.

I'll post up a couple of pictures later to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Set it up so that the lid can be used as a base for the pedal board while you're playing. You'll need to ensure a couple of things:

1. that the lid is strong enough to handle "missteps"; and
2. that the lid doesn't slip in either position (i.e., the lid holds its place against the frame of the pedal board through some sort of joint - maybe a lip).

If you do this, you may find that the best *shape* for everything is shallow rectangular at the sides for the pedal board casing, and somewhat wedge-shaped for the lid, with the wide end covering the pedals in transit, flipping around the rear while playing to raise the back a bit and angle the board towards you. If you do this, add some rubber feet on the lid.

**A** & **B** show (*very* roughly) closed and open. (The black thingie in **B** is meant to be a pedal.) **C** is a cross-section through the sides of the lid and case to show the kind of join I mean. You should only need fasteners to hold it closed in transit.

[image]

Doing it this way means you don't have to find a place to put the lid in cramped quarters. If that isn't a consideration, Dr Mayhem's suggestion *definitely* has the virtue of simplicity.